# SQL query to select all columns in a table except two columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table in ms-access with column names A to H

```
TableA 

A   B  C  D  E  F G  H
```

how can i write a query to select all columns except B and F columns. Query result should be

```
A C D E G H
```

Do we have something like this

```
select * from TableA except B, F ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you're stuck with

```
select a, c, d, e, g, h from TableA
```

Answer (score 3):

No, we don't. You have to use

```
SELECT A, C, D, E, G, H 
FROM TableA
```

And this is good if you ask me. SELECT * is evil enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
select A, C, D, E, G, H from TableA
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure, but it's ***definitely*** better to explicitly specify the columns you want to select. This makes any potential changes to your table easier to live with as you can use aliases etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
select A, C, D, E, G, H from TableA
```

or, create a view and select from that, as below:

```
CREATE VIEW vTableA
as   
select A, C, D, E, G, H from TableA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this.  It is '*' or just the fields you specify.  Is this a big problem?  Or is it just that you want something "neater"?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a pain in the ass, and I went on this forum to find another way to do this, but yeah, you're stuck defining each column. You can grab all the columns, though, by doing something like this:

```
select ',[' + column_name + ']'
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'your_table_name'
```

This way you can exclude the columns you don't want pretty quickly. It's especially useful when you have like 50+ columns.